# valuation of a composition in finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Let $P\in\mathbb F_q[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial, $Q\in\mathbb F_q[X]$. Do we have $v_P(Q(X^q))\ge v_P(Q)$ where $v_P$ denotes the $P$-valuation?

Obviously, if a root $x_0$ of $P$ is a root of $Q$, then $x_0$ is a root of $Q(X^q)$ too, but I do not manage to give a lower bound for its multiplicity.

Comment: Well, $Q(X^q)$ is just $Q(X)^q$.

Comment: Arf... I did not see that... Thanks!